# ReactJS App with REST API data is not displaying data correctly

Tags: reactjs, json

I am trying to make a React app that allows a user to select from the list of movies requested from a REST API I created. Once the user selects the movie, it displays the url as listed in the JSON API. I've researched many videos and articles and I'm not getting anywhere. Any help is appreciated to help me achieve what I am trying to do with this website. Attached is the screenshot of my progress so far and my code is below. I access the REST api through json-server --watch [json filename]

**Movies.js**

```
export default function Movies() {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false); 
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    const url = "http://localhost:8900/movies";[![enter image description here][1]][1]

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setMovies(result);
                },
                (error) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true);
                    setError(error);
                }
            )
    }, [])

    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <select value={(movies.title)}>
                    {movies.map(movie => (
                            <option value={movie.id}>
                                {movie.title}
                            </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <ul>
                {movies.map(item => (
                    <li>
                        <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                    </li>
                ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**test.json**

```
{
  "movies" : [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Space Jam: A New Legacy",
      "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3554046/"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "The War With Grandpa",
      "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4532038/"
    },
    {
      "id": 3, 
      "title": "Ghostbusters (1984)",
      "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087332/"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "Ghostbusters: Afterlife",
      "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4513678/"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "title": "Cruella",
      "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3228774/"
    },
    {
      "id": 6, 
      "title": "Here Today",
      "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10944596/"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "title": "The French Dispatch",
      "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8847712/"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "title": "Dazed and Confused",
      "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106677/"
    },
    {
      "id": 9, 
      "title": "Together Together",
      "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11285280/"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: App progress so far]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new state value `selectedMovie` then update it when your `select` change :

```js
const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState(movies[0]) // you can set whatever you want by default

const handleChange = (m) => {
  setSelectedMovie(JSON.parse(m.target.value));
}
```

Then, your select :

```
<select value={setSelectedMovie.title} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
        {movies.map((movie) => (
          <option key={movie.id} value={JSON.stringify(movie)}>{movie.title}</option>
        ))}
</select>
```

Then, you just have to display `selectedMovie` on your page

```
{ selectedMovie ? <a href={selectedMovie.url}>{selectedMovie.title}</a> : <p>Select movie</p> }
```

Comment: Everything worked up until attempting to display selectedMovie, however I was able to incorporate conditional rendering and instead of just displaying the link I used this: {selectedMovie ? <a href={selectedMovie.url}>{selectedMovie.title}</a> : <p>Select movie</p>}

Comment: Ok! I just edited that